# Issue parsing JSON Bing image results

Tags: java, json, bing-api

I am getting the following response from Bing Api when I send request for sourcetype Image

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?    Query='Xbox'&$skip=0&$top=1",
                    "type": "ImageResult"
                },
                "ID": "..",
                "Title": "STOCKS » XBOX",
                "MediaUrl": "http://blog.educastur.es/stocks/files/2010/12/xbox360.jpg",
                "SourceUrl": "http://blog.educastur.es/stocks/2010/12/20/xbox/",
                "DisplayUrl": "blog.educastur.es/stocks/2010/12/20/xbox",
                "Width": "1600",
                "Height": "1200",
                "FileSize": "733571",
                "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
                "Thumbnail": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "Bing.Thumbnail"
                    },
                    "MediaUrl": "http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4718224649029654&pid=15.1",
                    "ContentType": "image/jpg",
                    "Width": "300",
                    "Height": "225",
                    "FileSize": "11403"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and what I need is to get the `MediaUrl` from the `Thumbnail`. I am using the following code where I can get `title`, `description`, but not the `MediaUrl` of the `Thumbnail`.

```
public ArrayList<String> parseJson(String json){
    ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();
    List<String> res=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Map map = ob.readValue(json, Map.class);
        Object results = ((Map)map.get("d")).get("results");

        if(results instanceof ArrayList){

            for(Object o: (ArrayList)results){

               String thumbnail =  (String) ((Map) o).get("Thumbnail").get("MediaUrl"); //This does   not work
               res.add(thumbnail);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Couldn't parse JSON",e);
    }

    return res;

}
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Test it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I am sorry I did not post the whole json response for brevity. There is no issue with the response as I can get all the other fields except from the nested ones, e.g. url of thumbnail.

Comment: Your blocks are broken, the pairs of `{}` do not match. I've tried to fix as much as possible but it is still not valid Java. BTW: What is `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: I haven't posted the entire code because I have many dependencies in that. The blocks are OK. It is compiled and it is fine. The only issue is that I do not know how to get the Url thumbnail. Thank you again.

Comment: Tried this? `(String) (
((Map) 
  ((Map) o).get("Thumbnail")
).get("MediaUrl") )`

Comment: If it is "compiled and it is fine", then what is the question? If you're not going to provide an example other people can run independently, how do you expect us to debug it for you? Without other code, I'd say "Use GSON", but that is almost as unhelpful an answer, as your question. :)

Comment: I'd recommend [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), but yes, Jackson is messy...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've updated the initial block of code indicating where exactly my problem was, in order to prove useful for future reference. Moreover, I'd like to thank @DerFlatulator, I tried your solution and it worked. I know json-simple or gson may be better solutions, which I have also used in the past, but this time I had some restrictions to follow this way of parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting this from comments. It's extremely sloppy, but apparently works.

```
(String) ( ((Map) ((Map) o).get("Thumbnail") ).get("MediaUrl") );
```

I'd also like to re-state my recommendation of switching to [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) where possible.